# How I can place connection metadata in order to trace my queries on RDS performance insights fot my postgresql db?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

In my infrastructure I need to trace my queries to the execution location from AMAZON performance insights in case of a huge database load so I can refactor them. Each query is dynamically generated hence in my codebase are hard to be traced, also we are in a refactorring process as well.

Therefore I want to place on each query extra metadata so I can trace them better from my RDS perfomrance insights panel in case of a high load. Do you have any idea how I can do this?

The trace needs to be in the following 3 axis:

- Project
- File
- Line

So if I could provide this info at query execution level in my code I could trace them better.

Answer (score 0):

In many cases, the [application_name](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-APPLICATION-NAME) setting is shown for connections. If your database driver does not allow to set it when creating the connection, you can execute

```
SET application_name = '...';
```

at any time.

If your panel shows only the query text, then you have to add the information to the query text:

```
/* Hi, Mom! */ SELECT 42;
```

Comment: The `application_name` is set per connection? Can I change it on the fly?

Comment: Also how I can I change the `application_name` at query level as well?

Comment: Yes. Yes. You would have to change it before every query.